# Unable to get 100% on some islands

Tags: oceanhorn

I'm unable to get 100% completion on some islands, although I have

- All achievements
- All bloodstones (50)
- All (visible) chests

Also reviewed several walkthrough guides to see if I missed something, but no.

Isands I'm unable to finish:

- Great forest, 86%: unable to collect 4 coins in crypts (unacessable, not bombable)
- Graveyard island 91% (2 chests, this is a bug)
- Withered Lands 91%
- Tikarel 85%
- Sky Island 96%

Is this a bug?

**EDIT**

- On Graveyard island the developers have confirmed a bug that you cannot reach 2 chests that should not be there

**EDIT 2**

Percentage changes after the latest update:

- Hermit Island 113% (yes 113!)
- Graveyard Island jumped to 100%
- Great Forest 100% (1 more bloodstone below the boss ladder, got "Crimson Collector" with 54 Bloodstones)
- Withered Lands 91%
- Tikarel 100% (2 more bloodstones visible in crayfish cave)
- Sky Island 100% (1 more bloodstone in the outside area)

Although I got 113% on Hermit Island and 91% on Withered Lands I have 100% overall progress.

Comment: It might help to clarify which islands.